# Windows, Git and the SSH url/path of a bare repository

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cygwin, openssh

I am trying to set up a git repository on our Windows server.
I installed OpenSSH for Windows and Git for Windows.
The OpenSSH server runs on port 2345 to filter out generic bots.

I created a bare and shared repository on C:\git\protocolrepo.git
I couldn't reach it with the URL:

```
ssh://User@domain@server.com:2345:C:/git/protocol.git
```

It seems to me to be a malformed URL but everywhere I look on the web I get this, but it just doesn't work.

As I found out in this thread: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/895, the shell might be the cause, so I set the powershell as the default shell of OpenSSH.
This didn't work either and I still needed to use this oddly formed URL.
So I installed Cygwin and set the Cygwin bash as the default shell, and used a more appropriately formed url:

```
ssh://User@domain@server.com:2345/cygdrive/c/git/protocol.git
```

I had a little bit more success with this, but it now states the following error message:

```
fatal: '/cygdrive/c/git/protocol.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

The access rights should be fine as I make use of the same user alltogether, but I'm not 100% sure how this works on Windows.
I'm not sure either how Git/ssh handles this path on Windows.

On a Linux based server this worked just fine with `/git/protocol.git` path.

Pushing a new branch to a bare repository is something I haven't done in a while either so that also might be done wrong here, but I can't recall it to be an issue.

What would you recommend to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking if an interactive SSH session works, before considering using a Git repo SSH URL.

```
ssh -p 2345 User@domain@server.com
```

If it does, try and access `/C/git/protocol.git` in that interactive shell.

If that works, then try for your git commands the URL

```
ssh://User@domain@server.com:2345/C/git/protocol.git
# or
ssh://User@domain@server.com:2345/c/git/protocol.git
```

Comment: Hello mr. VonC, thanks your suggestion. I connected with ssh and I could reach directory of the repository at /cygdrive/c/git/protocol.git. I already had tested that. I suspect that the ssh url might be handled differently with git, maybe I need to set a git root directory or something like that. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: @Eyso The URL syntax you mentioned in the question was not the right one: can you try the one I mention in the answer?

Comment: I tried the URLs you suggested (well, adapted of course) but I get the same error message.

Comment: @Eyso in the interactive session, can you do a `ls /c/git/protocol.git`? Or is it possible only through `/cygdrive/c/git/protocol.git`?

Comment: only through /cygdrive/c/git/protocol.git

Comment: @Eyso Then would the  URL `ssh://User@domain@server.com:2345/cygdrive/c/git/protocol.git` work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212251/discussion-between-eyso-and-vonc).